# С разных компов сайт отображается по-разному

Tags: html, css

http://hellogoga.ru.swtest.ru/
Сам сайт, например, в самом низу есть раздел ПОКУПАТЬ У НАС ПРОСТО!

Так у неё отражается:

[image]

А так у меня:

[image]

Причём у себя я смотрел с разных компов, и всё нормально, а у неё так...

Намекните хоть, в какую сторону думать?

Comment: я смотрел, кстати, во всех современных браузерах - норм, она сказала, что и в хроме, и в опере, и с телефона всё плывёт.

Answer (score 1):

Пусть попробует обновить без кэша страницу. Мало-ли, что-то закэшировалось, и теперь "выплывает" подобным эффектом.

Но, в общем - странно. Такое чувство, что часть css-а не подгрузилась. (если только снизу сайта плывет.)

У меня - все нормально. Хром.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+F5 или открыть сайт в анонимном режиме. В MSIE Ctrl+F5 обязательно. Пусть еще в хроме или опере, если у нее не 12 Opera , нажмет Ctrl+Shift+F12 и скажет какие ошибки видны во вкладке консоль.

У меня светло-серый фон немного более узкий, чем тот, что над ним, темно-серый, пикселей на 15. Следовательно - баги в верстке. Chrome.

Comment: В хроме можно дважды нажать на CTRL+F5 )

Answer (score 0):

Если уж на моем разбитом ноутбуке (XP) в Хроме все нормально, значит и везде нормально)) Пусть она проверит на других компьютерах в офисе или у знакомых, есть ли такая ситуация. Причина может быть разная. Я например, пару раз отключила компьютер, вытащив вилку из розетки и у меня отлетела шапка на диспетчере задач. Но это не значит, что такая же ситуация происходит у всех. С сайтом все нормально. Пусть попробует переставить проблемные браузеры на новые версии и почистить компьютер (вирусы, реестр и тд.)

Answer (score 0):

Может, это из-за ошибок (на данный момент 50) - http://validator.w3.org

1) да ошибки где **An img element must have an alt attribute, except under certain conditions. For details, consult guidance on providing text alternatives for images.**
они на на внешний вид сайта не сыграют роль, но **alt for img** лучше все-таки прописать;

2) пропишите **title**;

3) **End tag ul seen, but there were open elements.** Это необходимо исправлять;

4) подключите одну библиотеку jquery - 
  сейчас у вас так:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
```

5) если доктайп HTML5 - тогда зачем так подключать <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">?